# Difference of two series in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields in MySQL: date, Value, Type.

Type can be either exports or imports.  I want a query that returns the trade deficit (exports-imports) for each month.  Is this possible with a single query?

Comment: What type of data goes into the Value column?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your date as a year/month/day in separate columns, or have some way to easily link to a table that lets you do, otherwise you have to do slow calculations on every `date` column to work out the month. I'll leave it like you've got it for now, but I would suggest storing dates differently to make this calculation easier (if you only ever group by month, then an extra column that stores the result of `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)` would make it much quicker overall.

Assuming "Value" is some kind of numeric:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) AS month,
    SUM(
        CASE Type
           WHEN 'export' THEN Value
           ELSE -1 * Value
        END
    ) AS trade_deficit
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)
```

(I haven't tested this, and there may be some syntax mixups, but it should work)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in one query, because you need 2 different WHERE clauses.

You can retrieve the exports with the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = month AND YEAR(date) = year AND Type = 'exports'
```

You can retrieve the imports with the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = month AND YEAR(date) = year AND Type = 'imports'
```

This assumes that Value is a numeric field and date is a DATETIME or a DATE field.

Sorry for the SQL on one line, but I don't know how to line break in the code sample.